# Protractor-trx-reporter not creating trx file

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm working with Protractor for the first time and I've installed some modules with NPM for protractor, protractor-trx-reporter, jasmine-trx-reporter, and webdriver-manager. Selenium server is running at the default 4444 port, and the tests seem to run fine when I run it locally through command line (opens a browser, test passes).

Everything seems to not give any errors, but I can't find the trx file published by the protractor-trx-reporter. When I run `protractor conf.js`, the test starts, and the command line output says that it's exporting the trx reporter and setting the output file to ProtractorTestResults.trx but a .trx file doesn't show up anywhere so I suspect it's not publishing a file but not throwing errors.

Any ideas if protractor-trx-reporter hasn't exported a trx file?

Here's what my config and spec files look like (both taken as samples from Protractor and protractor-trx-reporter sites)

```
    //conf.js
    exports.config = {
      framework: 'jasmine',
      seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
      specs: ['spec.js'],
      onPrepare: function () {
           console.log('Adding TRX reporter');
        require('protractor-trx-reporter');
           jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.TrxReporter('ProtractorTestResults.trx'));
      }
}

 //spec.js
 describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
     it('should add a todo', function() {
        browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

        element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
        element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

        var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
        expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
        expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');

        // You wrote your first test, cross it off the list
        todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
        var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
        expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);
     });
 });
```

Comment: any luck with this one, I'm having similar problem?

Comment: I actually ended up giving up on protractor-trx-reporter and switched to jasmine-trx-reporter, https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-trx-reporter, and that worked perfectly. :(

Comment: @Sachi I keep getting a trx is not defined error with jasmine-trx-reporter.

Comment: @Defpotec2020 Added my own answer to how I got it running, that should help you out.

Comment: @sachi, I had high hopes. I'm getting "no spec found" now when I run it with groupSuitesIntoSingleFile set to false. I get the trx not found error when I run it with groupSuitesIntoSingleFile set to true. No report in either case. And everything runs fine when I remove your code altogether (except of course no report generates). Any ideas on what might be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: And you're able to use protractor without the reporter and it runs fine? It seems weird that it would be throwing those errors. Do you still get that error with the code that I answered below?

Comment: @Sachi Yes I used your code. When I changed the framework from Jasmine 2 to just Jasmine in my conf file, it ran without errors, but node shows my file name constructor as a bunch of undefined's like it's not pulling in the data from JasmineTrxConfig. And no trx file is created. Was about to give up when it occurred to me that protractor-trx-reporter might work on Jasmine framework (just not jasmine 2.0) so I tried that and sure enough, it works. I don't know what the downside of jasmine vs jasmine 2 is though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using jasmine-trx-reporter, here's what the conf.js looked like:

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  directConnect: true,
  specs: ['spec.js'],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
onPrepare: function () {
        var trx = require('jasmine-trx-reporter');
        return browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
        var browserName = caps.get('browserName').toUpperCase();

        var jasmineTrxConfig = {
            reportName: 'Protractor Test Results',
            folder: 'testResults',
            outputFile: 'Test.trx',
            browser: browserName,
            groupSuitesIntoSingleFile: false
        };

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new trx(jasmineTrxConfig));
    });
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be the answer:

> "...short term we will not add support for Jasmine 2.0. Later on maybe
>   yes, but I can't promise you a date."

So that's upsetting. I'm having the same problem. And jasmine-trx-reporter isn't working for me either.

Source: [https://github.com/hatchteam/protractor-trx-reporter/issues/2]