# unable to produce trx file with jasmine-trx-reporter and protractor 3.3.0

Tags: jasmine, protractor, trx

I have tried generating the TRX logs with **jasmine-trx-reporter** and **protractor 3.3.0**

has anybody tried this before, let me know if you could able to generate one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor-trx-reporter not creating trx file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554261/protractor-trx-reporter-not-creating-trx-file)

Comment: hi, 
is jasmine-trx-reporter compatible with protractor 3.3.0, any idea?

Comment: I think it will support only 3.0.0 as per link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-trx-reporter

Comment: Hi Suresh,
Thanks for your input.
anyone knows with Protractor 3.3.0, how can i generate the TRX logs?